# Show that P is linearly ordered iff every maximal antichain in P has only one element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

If P is a partially ordered set, a subset A of P is called an *antichain* in P provided:

whenever $x,y \in A$ with $x \le y$ we have $x=y$.

(In other words, every pair of elements in an antichain are incomparable.)

GOAL: Show that P is linearly ordered if and only if every maximal antichain in P has a single element.

- If we let M be a maximal antichain of P, then M is not a proper subset of any other antichain.
- First, suppose every maximal antichain in P has only a single element. So let $a \in M: a \le a\le \cdots$ where a is the single element of the maximal antichain M in P. (I get stuck trying to get P linearly ordered probably because I'm not noticing some obvious fact.)
- Now, suppose P is a linearly ordered set. Then any two elements are comparable and P looks like: $p_1 \le p_2 \le p_3 \le \cdots$ where each p element is in P.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the definition of linear order? Or, perhaps even more explicitly, what is it that a partial order that is not a linear order must satisfy?

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $P$ is a linear order iff for all distinct elements have some relation between them.

Comment: @AndresE: A poset has a binary operation < on P with the following properties: reflexivity, transitivity, and an antisymmetric property (if a>b and b>a, then a=b). A totally ordered set has one additional property that any two elements must be comparable, that is for any two elements we have a<b or b<a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint in each direction:

Recall the defining feature of a linear order is that *every* pair of elements is comparable.

First, if $P$ is linearly ordered, then take any two elements $x$ and $y$. In an antichain, we must have $x \not \leq y$ and $y \not \leq x$. But what is the *one* thing we know about linear orders?

Conversely, if the largest antichain has size 1, then take two elements $x$ and $y$. Can you show they must be comparable (using an argument similar to the above)?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: If we take any two elements x and y in P they must be comparable. Therefore they cannot exist together and be incomparable as required in an antichain. So we conclude every maximal antichain in P must contain only one element. Looking at the reverse, every maximal antichain has size 1. Consider any two elements x and y in P. These elements lie in at least two antichains, and the union of these will contain both x and y (size 2). This union therefore no longer constitutes an antichain of P (by assumption). Now since they are no longer incomparable, it must be the case that they are comparable?

Comment: You've got it! ^_^